# C++ Compile time check if a function called before another one

Tags: c++, static-assert

Lets say I have a class with two member functions.

```
class Dummy {
 public:
  void procedure_1();
  void procedure_2();
};
```

**At compile time**, I want to be sure that, `procedure_1` is called before `procedure_2`. What is the correct way do implement this?

Comment: You can't. If `procedure_1` is called in some functions and `procedure_2` is called in some others then it's exceedingly difficult to know all the call paths

Comment: Or the calls might depend on some runtime value. Can you be more specific? For example, you could just write one function `void Dummy::procedure() { procedure_1(); procedure_2(); }` and make the other two private.

Comment: I would like to be able to call procedure_1() and procedure_2() separately. So I cannot combine them into a single call.

Comment: @phuclv, _exceedingly difficult_ seems not enough a reason to claim _you can't_.

Comment: Separate compilation makes this impossible in principle, let alone in practise.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to clarify what specifically you want or don't want. Some code examples would help too. Maybe you could use some kind of proxy classes that only expose one of the two functions.

Comment: There are also function pointers, which just adds to impossibility.

Comment: `procedure_2` could be private and invoked by the public `procedure_1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you could do it with a proxy-class. The idea is, that `procedure_2` can't be accessed directly from outside (for example by making it private). `procedure_1` would return some kind of proxy that allows the access to `procedure_2`.

Some code below, allthough I don't consider it clean or safe. And if you want, you can still break the system.

IMO such requirements should be handled without explicit validation, because it's quite cumbersome and impossible to make it absolutely safe.
Instead, the dependency should be well documented, which also seems idiomatic in C++. You get a warning that bad things might happen if a function is used incorrectly, but nothing prevents you from shooting your own leg.

```cpp
class Dummy {
private:
    void procedure_2() { }

    class DummyProxy
    {
        private:
            Dummy *parent; // Maybe use something safer here
        
        public:
            DummyProxy(Dummy *parent): parent(parent) {}
            
            void procedure_2() { this->parent->procedure_2(); }
    };
    
public:
    [[nodiscard]] DummyProxy procedure_1() {
        return DummyProxy{this};  
    }  
};

int main()
{    
    Dummy d;
    // d.procedure_2(); error: private within this context
    
    auto proxy = d.procedure_1();  // You need to get the proxy first
    proxy.procedure_2();           // Then 

    // But you can still break the system:  
    Dummy d2;
    decltype(d2.procedure_1()) x(&d2); // only decltype, function is not actually called
    d2.procedure_2(); // ooops, procedure_1 wasn't called for d2
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of "checking" it, just do not allow it. Do not expose an interface that allows to call it in any other way. Expose an interface that allows to *only* call it in specified order. For example:

```
// library.c
class Dummy {
private:
    void procedure_1();
    void procedure_2();
public:
    void call_Dummy_prodedure_1_then_something_then_produre_2(std::function<void()> f){
        procedure_1();
        f();
        procedure_2();
    }
};
```

You could also make `procedure_2` be called from destructor and `procedure_1` from a constructor.

```
#include <memory>

struct Dummy {
private:
    void procedure_1();
    void procedure_2();
public:
    struct Procedures {
        Dummy& d;
        Procedures(Dummy& d) : d(d) { d.procedure_1(); }
        ~Procedures() { d.procedure_2(); }
    };
    // just a simple example with unique_ptr
    std::unique_ptr<Dummy::Procedures> call_Dummy_prodedure_1_then_produre_2(){
        return std::make_unique<Dummy::Procedures>(*this);
    }
};
int main() {
    Dummy d;
    auto call = d.call_Dummy_prodedure_1_then_produre_2();
    call.reset(); // yay!
}
```

The above are methods that will make sure that inside one translation unit the calls will be ordered. To check between multiple source files, generate the final executable, then write a tool that will go through the generated assembly and if there are two or more calls to that `call_Dummy_prodedure_1_then_produre_2` function that tool will error. For that, additional work is needed to make sure that `call_Dummy_prodedure_1_then_produre_2` can't be optimized by the compiler.

But you could create a header that could only be included by one translation unit:

```
// dummy.h
int some_global_variable_with_initialization = 0;
struct Dummy {
    ....
};
```

and expose the interface from above into `Dummy` or add only the wrapper declaration in that library. That way, if multiple souce files include `dummy.h`, linker will error with `multiple definitions` error.

As for checking, you can make `prodedure_1` and `procedure_2` some macros that will expand to something that can't be optimized by the compiler with some mark, like assembly comment. Then you may go through generated executable with a custom tool that will check that the call to `prodedure_1` comes before `procedure_2`.